# Is reading Excel data by column labels supported in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

1. Shows the Excel file I'm trying to read from.
2. Shows what I want to do in non-legal code.
3. Shows what I have been trying so far.

1) Excel file

```
           A   |   B   |   C
    1    Name1   Name2   Name3
    2    33      44      55
    3    23      66      77
    4    22      33      99
```

2) Non-legal code:

```
frame = pd.read_excel(path, 'Sheet1', parse_cols="Name1,Name2,Name3")
```

In the example I can assume that the column names are unique.

3) Tried so far:

What I have been trying so far is to use `parse_cols`, but I don't think what I'm trying to do is supported by `pandas`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), there is no support for what you are trying to do. You can select columns by column number or column name, but not by column label:

> **parse_cols** : *int or list, default None*
>
> - If None then parse all columns,
> - If int then indicates last column to    be parsed
> - If list of ints then indicates list of column numbers to be    parsed
> - If string then indicates comma separated list of column names    and column ranges (e.g. “A:E” or “A,C,E:F”)